# DELETE FROM table WHERE NOT MAX

Tags: mysql, sql, max, notin

Okay so I have a table that has xid. Each xid can have several pids. I am trying to delete everything except the row that has the highest pid for each xid.

I am trying:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE `pid` NOT IN
( SELECT MAX(`pid`)
  FROM table
  GROUP BY `xid`
)
```

If I use the same query but with SELECT instead of DELETE, I get all of the records that I want to delete. When the DELETE is there, I get the error:

```
#1093 - You can't specify target table 'mod_personnel' for update in FROM clause
```

Comment: MySQL limitation...you can't refer to the table you are deleting/updating in a subselect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a JOIN rather than `NOT IN`:

```
DELETE t1.* FROM table t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT xid, MAX(pid) pid
           FROM table
           GROUP BY xid) t2
ON t1.pid = t2.pid
WHERE t2.pid IS NULL
```

Comment: I think you meant to also add `and t1.xid = t2.xid`  to the join.

Comment: @sgeddes That may be right, but the original query doesn't match on `xid`.

Comment: And he said that changing the original to a SELECT shows the correct set of rows. This is equivalent to his `NOT IN` attempt. My guess is that `pid` is unique, so it works either way.

Comment: Yeah, I was just thinking if it were unique, then it wouldn't be needed!  +1

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE `pid` NOT IN
(SELECT maxpid FROM
    ( SELECT MAX(`pid`) as maxpid
      FROM table
      GROUP BY `xid`
    )as m
)
```

Comment: Doesn't this run into the same restriction as the original query?